# Python: dbcur.execute AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, attributes, nonetype

I am trying to execute this peice of code:

```
def getServerSetting(self, setting):
    self.dbcur.execute('select value from settings where setting = ?', [str(setting)])
    rrf = self.dbr.fetchone()
    if rrf is None:
        return False
    else:
        return rrf[0]
```

However, I am getting this error when I run the python script:

```
dbcur.execute('select value from settings where setting = ?', [str(setting)])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: Did you bother trying to give it a meaningful value?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I believe I have it defined earlier in the code here: dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                               user='removed',
                               passwd='removed',
                               db='removed',
                               port=21)
     dbcur = dbcon.cursor()'

Comment: @ChrisArena How do I fix that?

Comment: did you mean to assign `self.dbcur = dbcon.cursor()` earlier?

Comment: @Gerrat Yes I do have it defined as 'dbcur = dbcon.cursor()' earlier.

Comment: No.  You need **self**.dbcur = dbcon.cursor().  It looks like you're missing the `self`

Comment: No I get the error instance has no attribute dbcur @Gerrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write your function like this. If there are still errors, show me.

```
def getServerSetting(self, setting):

    if not self.dbcon:
        self.dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='removed', passwd='removed', db='removed', port=21)
    self.dbcur = self.dbcon.cursor()

    self.dbcur.execute('select value from settings where setting = ?', [str(setting)])
    rrf = self.dbr.fetchone()
    if rrf is None:
            return False
    else:
            return rrf[0]
```

Comment: This is the error I got: TransformiceServer instance has no attribute 'dbcon'

Comment: @tr3y put self.dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='removed', passwd='removed', db='removed', port=21)
    self.dbcur = self.dbcon.cursor() in __init__() of TransformiceServer and try again

Comment: New error though, now the error says:

line 1846, in sendProfile
    ava = str(self.server.getUserAvatar[username])
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @tr3y I'm afraid you have to dig by yourself. It seems a big project.